# How do I get Elementor single post template content in loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I had created a single post template for custom post type in Elementor Builder. I want to call the layout at frontend inside loop to let user to view the content without click the post url and go to the post inner page. I want to show this loop at the other page which is not a single post inner.

```
$content = "";

if (class_exists("\\Elementor\\Plugin")) {
    $post_ID = get_the_ID();
    $pluginElementor = \Elementor\Plugin::instance();
    $content = $pluginElementor->frontend->get_builder_content_for_display($post_ID);
}

echo $content;
```

This is the php code I tried. But this return empty result. What should I do to call the layout? Thanks in advance.